# The electric current in a circuit comprising a battery, an ideal wire and a few resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

How will the electric current in this circuit flow? Assuming that the current starts flowing from the positive(+ve) terminal (Conventional current), will it flow entirely through the branch between the 2Ω and the 1Ω resistor offering no resistance {Ideal} or will it flow through both the paths{Through the middle branch and the 1Ω resistor}? and if it flows through both paths, then why is that the case? Current as far as I know, prefers a path which offers the least resistance. In this case, shouldn't it pass entirely through the middle branch with no resistance?

Comment: Is there a connection where the two lines cross at the center? And where is the reference node?

Comment: There is no connection between the two lines crossing at the centre.

Comment: Consider the potential at the positive terminal "V" and the potential at the other terminal 0.

Comment: This question might be silly but I am confused. Maybe, I'm lacking some important concepts.

Comment: Try redrawing the circuit with no crossings, then it will be much easier to analyze.

Comment: Thank you!! I've done that but I don't know why I'm feeling confused, although this might not be tough, I feel that I'm lacking conceptual clarity. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a multi step process:

1. Redraw the circuit without the crossing traces.
2. Add a trace, see which resistances are shorted out, and then redraw without those resistances.
3. Repeat step 2 for the last trace.

At the end of process, the actual path the electrons take will become clear